# Ansible Molecule Test Unable to Connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: docker, ansible, gitlab-ci, molecule

I create the default test role by running `molecule init scenario default`

Then I run `molecule test`

**Output from GitLab CI is as follows:**

```
"stderr": "\u001b[31mERROR: Unable to contact the Docker daemon. Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ for managing the daemon\u001b[0m\n\u001b[31mERROR: Unable to contact the Docker daemon. Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ for managing the daemon\u001b[0m",
     "stderr_lines": [
         "\u001b[31mERROR: Unable to contact the Docker daemon. Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ for managing the daemon\u001b[0m",
         "\u001b[31mERROR: Unable to contact the Docker daemon. Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ for managing the daemon\u001b[0m"
```

**Molecule role is as follows:**

```
- name: Create Default Role
  command: molecule init scenario default
  args:
    chdir: roles/amazon_cloudwatch_agent

- name: Run Molecule Test
  command: molecule --debug test
  args:
    chdir: roles/amazon_cloudwatch_agent
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to redesign the gitlab-ci.yml file as so:

```
---

image: <insert desired image here> 
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - tests

before_script:
  - docker -v
  - python -V
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install molecule
  - pip install -U requests==2.5.3

molecule-role-common:
  stage: tests
  tags:
  - molecule
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    PY_COLORS: 1
  script:
    - cd roles/amazon_cloudwatch_agent; molecule init scenario --role-name amazon_cloudwatch_agent
    - ls
    - molecule --debug test
```

It seems having services: docker:dind is the key to get the docker image molecule runs connecting with the docker daemon.

While I am still having issues with the proxy, this has gotten me past the initial problem encountered.